# How to add all SHOW permissions to user?

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, syntax-error

I'm having trouble with adding user permissions.
After entering this:

```
CREATE USER 'operator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '7gx8vq95wqgu3qcp';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE ON AGD.* TO 'operator'@'localhost';
```

A syntax error pops up. I guess it's about this part:

```
SHOW
```

I wanted to add these permissions: select, update insert, delete , all show and all create .
Unfortunately I can't find it anywhere on the internet.
I will be grateful if you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose between

```
CREATE USER 'operator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '7gx8vq95wqgu3qcp';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE ON AGD.* TO 'operator'@'localhost';

CREATE USER 'operator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '7gx8vq95wqgu3qcp';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ON AGD.* TO 'operator'@'localhost';
```

see [all privilges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)